# Free Spirit bike - please help ID

Tags: identify-this-bike

I found this bike being sold on Mercari and fell in love with it! Unfortunately, the item was deleted and I was unable to get a hold of it.

I’ve been researching everything Free Spirit (lots of adult multi-speed and bmx bikes) and can’t find this specific model or even something similar.

It was listed as a “kids bike,” single speed, and I’m assuming coaster brake. It was never confirmed if it’s a 20”.

Thanks for your help if you have any info[image: Red Free Spirit bike with chrome front and rear fenders, rear rack, cruiser handle bars]

Answer (score 4):

It looks a lot like the [1972 Sears Free Spirit](https://stumptownbikes.blogspot.com/2014/04/used-bicycles-and-other-games-of-chance.html) in this post.

Bike makers used different decals on the same bike at different times.
This frame was used in different configurations for single speed coaster brake bikes, three speed, five speed and ten speed bikes.

If you had access to Sears catalogs from 1970 to 1975 you could probably hunt down the exact decals and configuration.

[image]

According to the post:

> It’s a 1972 Free Spirit Sheffield sold by Sears.
> this bike is actually made by a bicycle manufacturer called Puch in Austria.

I believe both of these bikes have 24 inch wheels, this would explain why it's sold as a children's bike. Adult versions of this bike in this era had 26 inch wheels.

Finding a bike exactly like the red coaster brake bike can be tricky - they come and go.
If you broaden your search to a "ladies coaster brake bicycle" you will find a lot more options to choose from.

Two suggestions:

- Stick with brand names you recognize as bicycle makers.
- Never buy anything without riding it.

As a rule of thumb I try to stay away from anything branded as Sears. The bike pictured here would be an exception. In the 80s and 90s Sears sold thousands (millions?) of poorly made and assembled bicycles.

Comment: If you look at the original photo, it has pedals and saddle that are much larger in proportion to wheels. My guess is that they are not huge but the wheels are instead small.

Comment: The OP's image is obviously of a shorter bike, with what appear to be 20 inch tires, while the above image has 24 or 26 inch tires.  But they are very much the same style, right down to the pattern of the chainring.  And the cottered cranks suggest a year earlier than the late 70s.

Answer (score 3):

I had one of these bikes. The tires are a very odd size and are very hard to replace. Mine had no sidewalls and the tubes were folded mountain bike tubes. The bike itself is very small but the wheels are slightly too big to fit regular 20" tires. I can't find much info on it, but it was a fun bike while I had it. Sold it a long time ago for $13.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Do you have any info on the model number or model year or anything else that might help the OP?